# Fancybox 2.01 onclose command?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I've just downloaded fancybox 2.01 from here : http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

In earlier versions of fancybox (1.x) I had an option to use onClosed to do some stuff.. I can't find that opportunity in 2.0.. Can that be true? Or can anyone tell me how to make an event (like updating an ajax div) on close of a fancybox??

Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I this "beforeClose" option can be used for what you want.
For reference check: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs  Callback tab
Hope it helps

Comment: great... I oversaw that there was a callback tab.. sorry!! and thanks!!